# Monogame Soundeffect doesn't play

Tags: c#, opengl, directx, monogame

I'm making a game with Monogame.

I use 2 computers to program, both Windows 8 x64 with VS 2013 Prof
On one of my computers I don't have any problem. The sound just works (I'm using the DX version).

On my other computer it doesn't the exact same code...
I changed it to the OpenGL backend and then I works...
But the OpenGL version of the game is 3 times bigger.

I really don't understand it.
Does someone have experience with this?

```
_soundJump = content.Load<SoundEffect>("Jump");
```

I converted a .wav 16 signed PCM to a xnb file.

Comment: With the last release, I had similar problems. After looking for a good while, the conclusion was that monogame had a bug with sound handling. Did you try to ask this on their forums?

Answer (score 1):

[Monogame: WAV not playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011883/monogame-wav-not-playing)

After reinstalling DirectX (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35&84e4d527-1a2f-c70a-8906-a877ec4baada=1) the SoundEffect class started working again!

Comment: This solution worked for me with monogame version 1.6.